# How is Documentation meant to be searched/found?

Tags: discussion, documentation

In its current form, SO Documentation revolves around examples that are organized into topics. Each topic has no more than 13 examples, and examples have a maximum length. Given this criteria, how exactly are we expecting users to find this information?

**An example:**
Lets say I'm searching for a quick example of how `Array.prototype.reduce` works. Generally, I'll go to google and search for "array reduce mdn" and the first result is exactly the page I want. If I instead wanted a result from SO Documentation, what am I supposed to type? "sodocs" doesn't pull up so docs, so am I expected to type out "site:stackoverflow.com/documentation"? Are we expecting it to just organically become relevant when someone searches "javascript array reduce"? I don't see a path that would get us there in the current iteration. Currently, the first SO result points us to a [QA pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732043/javascript-reduce-on-array-of-objects)

The question/answer it brings us to is good, but what good is that example in SO Documentation doing us if we can't find it? What can we do to make it more discoverable? Should it be more discoverable?

Comment: disclaimer, i use a personal block list extension to block w3schools... so even searching for "javascript array reduce" pulls up mdn, not w3schools. i'd suggest everyone to do that.

Comment: Even when i do a sitesearch from google, it takes me to the Array topic, not directly to the array.prototype.reduce example in that topic. Would tags on examples help at all?

Comment: I think there is a lot of room for improvement on this topic, and that it should be both more integrated and discoverable.